# Perl oneliner where slurps @ARGV

Tags: perl

I am looking for a Perl oneliner (inserting it into Bash script), and I need the next interface:

```
perl -0777 -nlE 'commands' file1 file2 .... fileN
```

I created the next:

```
perl -0777 -lnE 'BEGIN{$str=quotemeta(do{local(@ARGV, $/)="file1"; <>})} say "working on $ARGV" if $_ =~ /./' "$@"
```

Prettier:

```
perl -0777 -lnE '
    BEGIN{
        $str = quotemeta(
            do{
                local(@ARGV, $/)="file1"; <>  #localize ARGV to "file1.txt" for <>
            }
        )
    }
    say "working on $ARGV" if $_ =~ /./   #demo only action
' "$@"
```

It works, but with this I need edit the source code every time when needing to change `file1`.

How do I change the script to the following?

- Slurp the `$ARGV[0]` (file1) into `$str` (in the BEGIN block)
- And slurp the other arguments into `$_` in the main loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it as an argument, removing it from `@ARGV` in the `BEGIN` block.

```
$ echo foo >refile

$ echo -ne 'foo\nbar\nfood\nbaz\n' >file1

$ echo -ne 'foo\nbar\nfood\nbaz\n' >file2

$ perl -lnE'
   BEGIN {
      local @ARGV = shift(@ARGV);
      $re = join "|", map quotemeta, <>;
   }
   say "$ARGV:$.:$_" if /$re/;
   close(ARGV) if eof;  # Reset $.
' refile file1 file2
file1:1:foo
file1:3:food
file2:1:foo
file2:3:food
```

Comment: The assignment operator evaluates its RHS operand before its LHS operand. It allows things like `perl -E'my $x="abc"; { my $x = uc($x); say $x; } say $x;'`